# Interval Validation

Tags: javascript, validation

We have three different web pages that contain grid which is for adding details of master entity.

Detail object can be expressed in javascript by

```
var detail = {
     Description: 'Detail',
     MinPercentage: 0,
     MaxPercentage: 20
}
```

Now, we want to validate these details before sending to server.

### Validations

- There must not be any intersection. i.e. detail('Detail1', 0, 20) and detail('Detail2', 15, 30) are not valid, because between 15 and 20 are in common.
- Details hold values from given minimum value to given maximum value. i.e.detail('Detail1', 0, 20) and detail('Detail2', 20, 40) hold values from 0 to 40. If given minimum is 0 and given maximum is 40, they are valid.

### Expectations from Function

- Because I want to write a function to use in multiple places, that should be as generic as possible.

Then, I wrote a function named **areIntervalsValid** but I am not sure how to handle calls with wrong inputs, throw exceptions, return best structured result and also I am wondering what is the best way to perform validations.

---

```
// Returns array of detail object to test.
var getDetails = function () {
    var detail1 = { Description: 'Detail1', MinPercentage: 0, MaxPercentage: 20 }
    var detail2 = { Description: 'Detail2', MinPercentage: 40, MaxPercentage: 60 }
    var detail3 = { Description: 'Detail3', MinPercentage: 60, MaxPercentage: 72 }
    var detail4 = { Description: 'Detail4', MinPercentage: 72, MaxPercentage: 100 }
    var detail5 = { Description: 'Detail5', MinPercentage: 20, MaxPercentage: 40 }

    return new Array(detail1, detail2, detail3, detail4, detail5);
}

// Performs type checking, logical validation, and requirements validation.
var areIntervalsValid = function (items, min, max, minProperty, maxProperty) {
    // Returned object.
    var result = {
        Success: false,
        Message: ''
    }

    // Checks arguments have expected types.
    var validateFunctionCall = function () {
        if (!Array.isArray(items) || typeof min !== 'number' || typeof max !== 'number' || typeof minProperty !== 'string' || typeof maxProperty !== 'string')
            throw 'An error occurred while processing validation.';
        if (!items.length || min > max)
            throw 'An error occurred while processing validation.';
    }

    // Checks [minProperty] of detail that has minimum [minProperty] == min
    // and [maxProperty] of detail that has maximum [minProperty]
    var validateIntervalBasics = function () {
        if (items[0][minProperty] != min || items[items.length - 1][maxProperty] != max)
            throw 'Start and end values of interval do not match minimum - maximum values.';
    }

    // Checks @item has [minProperty] and [maxProperty].
    var validateHasProperty = function (item) {
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(minProperty) || !item.hasOwnProperty(maxProperty)) {
            throw 'An error occurred while processing validation.';
        }
    }

    try {
        validateFunctionCall();

        // Sorts array of details in according to [minProperty].
        items.sort(function (item1, item2) { return item1[minProperty] > item2[minProperty] });

        validateIntervalBasics();

        var totalDiff = 0, currentItem;

        // Algorithm part. 
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            currentItem = items[i];
            validateHasProperty(currentItem);
            totalDiff += currentItem[maxProperty] - currentItem[minProperty];
            if (i != items.length - 1 && currentItem[maxProperty] > items[i + 1][minProperty]) { // Finds intersections.
                throw "There are intersected values: " + currentItem[maxProperty] + " - " + items[i + 1][minProperty];
            }
        }

        // Checks second validation.
        if (totalDiff != max - min) {
            throw 'Total interval sum is not equal to ' + (max - min);
        }

        result.Success = true;

        return result;

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        result.Message = e;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, I call the function like that:

```
areIntervalsValid(getDetails(), 0, 100, "MinPercentage", "MaxPercentage");
```

What can I do to the function to be more reliable, generic, and fast?

Comment: Is this code currently working as intended, and you just want to improve it?

Comment: Are maximum and minimum inclusive or exclusive ? If you get Detail1(0, 50) and Detail2(50, 100), that means 49.99999 is part of Detail1 and 50.00001 is part of Detail2, but what about 50 ?

Comment: @SebastienC. minimum is inclusive, maximum is exlusive.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan yeah it works. Because the question is not all about algorithm but also javascript, I wrote that down here.

Comment: @dewe [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) might be better suited for this, they offer critique and suggestions to improve code that's already working. I might be misunderstanding your question though, so please read their site tour before asking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished in nicer way if you use functional programming principles - recursion especially.

There is my solution for this problem. There is no data type validation logic because I believe you can do it yourself:

```js
// Numbers and intervals comparison logic
function intervalsIntersect(start1, end1, start2, end2) {
  return inBetween(start1, start2, end2) || inBetween(end1, start2, end2);
}

function inBetween(value, start, end){
  return Math.max.apply(null, arguments) != value && Math.min.apply(null, arguments) != value;
}

// Validation logic
function getDetailsIntersectionReport(interval1, interval2) {
  var comparisonResult = intervalsIntersect(interval1.MinPercentage, interval1.MaxPercentage, interval2.MinPercentage, interval2.MaxPercentage);
  return comparisonResult ? ('[' + interval1.Description + ' instersects with ' + interval2.Description + '], ') : '';
}

function compareHeadWithTailFunctionFactory(head, comparatorFunction) {
  return function ( previous, item) {
    return previous + comparatorFunction(head, item);
  }
}

// you have to inject custom comparator function to make this function generic
function validateWithReport(list, comparatorFunction) {
  if (list.length <= 1) { // return if there is nothing to compare
    return '';
  }
  var head = list[0];
  var tail = list.slice(1);
  return tail.reduce(compareHeadWithTailFunctionFactory(head, comparatorFunction), 
  '' // initial value - empty string
  ) + validateWithReport(tail, comparatorFunction);

}

function validateIntervals(intervals) {
  var result = validateWithReport(intervals, getDetailsIntersectionReport);
  if (result.length) {
    throw new Error('There are intersecting intervals: ' + result);
  }
  return true;
}

// Unit test with Jasmine
describe('validation with report', function() {
  
  var intervalsWithoutIntersections = [
    { Description: 'Detail1', MinPercentage: 0, MaxPercentage: 20 },
    { Description: 'Detail2', MinPercentage: 40, MaxPercentage: 60 },
    { Description: 'Detail3', MinPercentage: 60, MaxPercentage: 72 }
  ];

  var intervalsWithIntersections = [
    { Description: 'Detail4', MinPercentage: 0, MaxPercentage: 21 },
    { Description: 'Detail5', MinPercentage: 20, MaxPercentage: 60 },
    { Description: 'Detail6', MinPercentage: 60, MaxPercentage: 72 }
  ];  
  
  it('should report with exception about error', function() {
    expect( function() { // wrapping into closure to catch error properly
      validateIntervals(intervalsWithIntersections)
    }).toThrowError();
  });

  it('should report validation with true', function() {
    expect(validateIntervals(intervalsWithoutIntersections)).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```